# Trying to build a WinForms application with all satellite resource assemblies included

Tags: c#, winforms, msbuild, ilmerge, satellite-assembly

I'm using VS 2013 to build a C# WinForms application that ships as a single EXE file. So far, this was no problem using ilmerge as a post-build step in order to include all needed DLLs. Even ActiveX components can be embedded without problems.

But now, I am going to internationalize the application which results in localized satellite resource assemblies being generated. My current solution is as follows:

1. Build generates DLL under (e.g.) .....`\en\MyApp.resources.dll`
2. Post-build action copies this DLL into `..\..\Resources\i18n\en`

The next time Build is executed, it embeds the resource under resource folder `i18n\en` as Embedded Resource into the target. In my application I use my own `ResolveEventHandler` for the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, reading the requested DLL from the application's internal resources.

This works fine, BUT: After committing changes that involve the localized DLL, I have to build the solution twice in order to get the new DLL into the output EXE.

Using `ilmerge` for including the satellite assemblies was not successful because it unpacks the DLLs and puts the objects contained therein directly into the EXE file.

So, my question is whether I can modify the .csproj file in such a way that after generating the DLL I can copy it into the resource directory *before* the resources are packed into the output binary, instead of copying *after* the first build. That way only one build pass would be necessary and errors could be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now, but in a different way than I was looking for initially.

Instead of embedding the DLL as an Embedded Resource using Visual Studio / MS Build, I made a tool *ResourceEmbedder* for embedding resources afterwards. It uses [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to accomplish this. So the mechanism is now:

1. Build the target EXE file the standard VS way.
2. Post-build: Use the **ResourceEmbedder** tool to embed all satellite assemblies.
3. Post-build: Use **ilmerge** to embed all external DLLs.
4. At runtime, hook into the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event in order to supply the satellite assemblies when needed.